# python pywhatkit module take much time to install and not install in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using vs code in linux(raspberry pi 4), when i am trying to install pywhatkit python module using pip, pip3 install pywhatkit, it download some data of pywhatkit, after some time it freeze at line (Running setup.py bdist_wheel for opencv-python ...)

```
Collecting pywhatkit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/27/19c5271c06a8cc6c8f8716728d42416a9bee93016a916b69bb338eff99dd/pywhatkit-2.9-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pywhatkit) (0.9.50)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pywhatkit) (1.4.0)
Collecting opencv-python (from pywhatkit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/f5/49f034f8d109efcf9b7e98fbc051878b83b2f02a1c73f92bbd37f317288e/opencv-python-4.4.0.42.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze>=0.1.21 in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.26)
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pygetwindow>=0.0.5 in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-Xlib; platform_system == "Linux" and python_version >= "3.0" in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrect in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pygetwindow>=0.0.5->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mouseinfo->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.8.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for opencv-python ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Author of Pywhatkit here.

Pywhatkit has dependencies on Opencv-python library which is about 80MB and takes some time to install, especially when the Internet is slow.
I am looking forward to find an alternative method in place of using this big library and I will release new update asap.

Alternatively, try installing Opencv separately or install some previous version of pywhatkit (<=2.8).